# Meta Tags: Events vs Community Events

Tags: discussion

There's an [events](/questions/tagged/events) tag and a [community-events](/questions/tagged/community-events) tag on meta.

it's about a 14-17 split.

Are these being used for the same purpose? can we/I merge these tags?

Comment: Quite a few of them overlap. I think merging them would be a good move.

Comment: Yeah they're the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there are any objections, I will make [events](/questions/tagged/events) the main tag with community-events as a synonym - as it is shorter and more obvious.

Comment: It has been done.